# How to add days to a date in Java

Tags: java, date

I want to add days to a date to get a new date in Java. How to achieve it using the `Calendar` class.

```
Calendar dom = new GregorianCalendar(d, m, y);
```

is the instance of my date of manufacture and I want to reach to date of expiry adding some 100 days to the current date and store it in a variable `doe` but unable to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make use of [`Calendar#add()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29). Here's a kickoff example.

```
Calendar dom = Calendar.getInstance();
dom.clear();
dom.set(y, m, d); // Note: month is zero based! Subtract with 1 if needed.
Calendar expire = (Calendar) dom.clone();
expire.add(Calendar.DATE, 100);
```

If you want more flexibility and less verbose code, I'd recommend [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) though.

```
DateTime dom = new DateTime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime expire = dom.plusDays(100);
```

Comment: thanks a ton. But when I try to make new instance of calenar with added value as new date it is not storing it in new instance.

Comment: You shouldn't do `new GregorianCalendar(d, m, y)`. Follow the same steps as here above. That's the only right way. Besides, note that you should put `y, m, d` in and not `d, m, y`. Also note that the month is zero based. January is 0, February is 1, March is 2, etc. It's a nightmare, the `Calendar`.

Comment: Quick question - Why do you recommend against new GregorianCalendar(...)?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) It's a better practice to program to the interface/abstract class. 2) You really need to `clear()` the calendar to avoid clashes sooner or later when cloning/comparing/etc.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Never use `Calendar`. Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) for date-only values.

```
LocalDate.of( 2015 , 2 , 3 ).plusDays( 100 )
```

## java.time

Now, years later, the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are supplanted by the new java.time package in Java 8 and later.

These new classes include a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class for representing a date-only without time-of-day nor time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2015 , 2 , 3 ) ;
LocalDate later = localDate.plusDays( 100 );
```

That code above works for dates. If you instead need to know exact moment of expiration, then you need time-of-day and time zones. In that case, use `ZonedDateTime` class.

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = later.atStartOfDay( zone ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateFormat formatter = null;
    Date convertedDate = null;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(pro.getDate().toString());//pro.getDate() is the date getting from database
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(convertedDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        Date cvdate=cal.getTime();
    if (cvdate.after(new Date())){
 //do Something if you show expire...
}
```