# Date Computaion in java

Tags: java, date

The date format iam using is "MM/dd/yy"
I want to perform a operation like This:

```
LastActDate = Todaysdate -(PrchaseDate + 1)
```

In myDb the date is stored as 2011-07-08 19:30:06(java util date

Comment: What's stopping you from performing the operation?  What code do you have?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add days to a date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507377/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Calendar.add(int field, int amount)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29)

> Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar
>   field, based on the calendar's rules.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Calendar;

class AddDates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
        Calendar purchased = new GregorianCalendar();

        purchased.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        Calendar lastActDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        lastActDate.setTimeInMillis(today.getTimeInMillis() - purchased.getTimeInMillis());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [joda library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for any date/time calculations.

You can do the kind of work you want to do above with it very easily just take a look at examples on the site.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Assuming the +1 is "plus one day".

```
try {
    String dateString = "10/20/11";

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    Date dt = df.parse(dateString);

    final long ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;      
    Date lastActDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (dt.getTime() + ONE_DAY));

    String lastActDateString = df.format(lastActDate);
}
catch ( ParseException pe ) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should always use a Calendar for date calculations in java.