# How to add days into the date in android

Tags: android, date

In my database I am getting start date like 2011-11-30(yyyy/mm/dd)format.and duration date like 40 days.How can i calculate the days and get new date format of mm/dd/yyyy.

Can anyone help me

Thanks

Comment: look for java's date functions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add days to a date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507377/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-java)

Answer (score 98):

You can try something like this,

```
String dt = "2012-01-04";  // Start date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 40);  // number of days to add, can also use Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH in place of Calendar.DATE
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
String output = sdf1.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: A side note, Calendar.DATE is synonymous with Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, which might be more readable

Comment: @Styler added in the comment. Thanks.

Comment: While this was a fine answer in 2012, I recommend we no longeruse `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 29):

**Step-1** Get Calendar instance from the specified string

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(sdf.parse(dateInString));
```

**Step-2** use `add()` to add number of days to calendar

```
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 40);
```

**Step-3** Convert the dtae to the resultant date format

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date resultdate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
            dateInString = sdf.format(resultdate);
```

**Source Code**

```
String dateInString = "2011-11-30";  // Start date
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(sdf.parse(dateInString));
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 40);  
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date resultdate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
        dateInString = sdf.format(resultdate);
        System.out.println("String date:"+dateInString);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Date dtStartDate=o.getStartDate();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dtStartDate);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);  // number of days to add
String dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
Toast.makeText(this, "" + dt, 5000).show();
```

Comment: This is example adds 3 days. If you want 3 days ago, change the parameter to -3.

Answer (score 8):

This code  is working 100%

```
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");// HH:mm:ss");
            String reg_date = df.format(c.getTime());
            showtoast("Currrent Date Time : "+reg_date);

            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);  // number of days to add
            String end_date = df.format(c.getTime());
            showtoast("end Time : "+end_date);
```

Answer (score 6):

**This piece of code should do the job well!!!**

```
public static String addDay(String oldDate, int numberOfDays) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(oldDate));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,numberOfDays);
    dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY");
    Date newDate=new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    String resultDate=dateFormat.format(newDate);
    return resultDate;
}
```

*For more functionality do please checkout this link*
[Add days,months,years to a date](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Date-Type/AdddayMonthandyeartoaDate.htm)

Comment: `oldDate` in `c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(oldDate));` is a Date, the function is expecting a Date.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

The modern answer to this question is long overdue. Do consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
    int durationDays = 40;
    
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("2011-11-30");
    LocalDate newDate = startDate.plusDays(durationDays);
    
    String formattedDate = newDate.format(outputFormatter);
    System.out.format(formattedDate);
```

Output is:

> 01/09/2012

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // display the current date
    String CurrentDate = mYear + "/" + mMonth + "/" + mDay;

    String dateInString = CurrentDate; // Start date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    c = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        c.setTime(sdf.parse(dateInString));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7656);//insert the number of days you want to be added to the current date
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date resultdate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    dateInString = sdf.format(resultdate);

    //Display the Result in the Edit Text or Text View your Choice
    EditText etDOR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDateOfReturn);
    etDOR.setText(dateInString);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

String CurrentDate = mYear + "/" + mMonth + "/" + mDay;
String dateInString = dob; // Select date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
c = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dateInString));
} catch (ParseException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 14);    //14 dats add
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date resultdate = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
dateInString = sdf.format(resultdate);
System.out.println(dateInString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Use this instead:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar =new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH , 30);
```

Comment: What is reason for "Don't use", did you come across a bug or something?!

Answer (score -1):

Just Simple copy this method pass data

```
public static String ConvertToDate(String dateString,String inputFormater ,String outputFormater) {
        String outputText = "" ;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormater);
            SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormater);
            Date parsed = null;
            parsed = inputFormat.parse(dateString);
            outputText = outputFormat.format(parsed);

        Log.d(TAG, "  msg : " + outputText);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return outputText;
    }
```

And call it like

```
 public static String INPUTE_JSON_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
 public static String FORMAT_FOR_JOB_APPLIED = "MMM dd, yyyy";
 String date ="2017-10-29";
 ConvertToDate(date ,DateUtils.INPUTE_JSON_DATE_FORMAT ,DateUtils.FORMAT_FOR_JOB_APPLIED);
```

You can put any format you want in your cituation

```
ConvertToDate("2011-11-30","yyyy/mm/dd" ,"mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: The question is how to add days to a date.