# Dynamically updating time in android

Tags: java, android

### I am trying to do something on time-updation in Android.

---

**My specification is**:

- When i compile the project my activity must display two `edittext`
  fields.
- Assume todays date is `26/DEC/2013` first edittext field must display
  that
- and for the next exit text field it must display `2/JAN/2014`
- This means the edit text must dynamically update time from
  `today(first-edit-text)` till next `7 days(second-edit-text)`

---

**Snapshot**:

[image]

---

**I just have basic code structure**:

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="From" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="To" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

---

***My Questions***

1. How can i achieve this in android
2. Any guidance on how to proceed will be helpful

**Note**: I am not speaking about using date picker; I am trying achieve this without it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date and then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738369/how-to-add-days-into-the-date-in-android. check this if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your **MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        EditText edt;
        EditText edt2;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     edt2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);   
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
     c1.setTime(new Date());
     c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
     c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); // Adding 7 days
     String ToDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
     String FromDate = sdf.format(c1.getTime());
     edt2.setText(FromDate);
     edt.setText(ToDate);

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You just get Today's Date into this particular Format:

```
Calendar c22 = Calendar.getInstance();      
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
String cur_date = sdf.format(c22.getTime());
editText1.setText(cur_date);
```

and now add 7 days into today's date:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); // Adding 7 days
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
String nxt_date = sdf.format(c.getTime());
editText2.setText(nxt_date);
```

try this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do following :

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());

    edttext1.setText((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    //This will set the current date 

    //Now extend your date 7 days ahead 
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
    edttext2.setText((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567659/calculate-elapsed-time-in-java-groovy/1776721#1776721)

and calculate time on onStart method of your activity.