# android java parse date from string

Tags: java, android, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat

In android application I'm trying to parse Date from string to find difference between two times.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatDateAndTime = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHMM");
Date startDateTime = dateFormatDateAndTime.parse("060420150134");
Log.v(TAG, "startDateTime: " + startDateTime);  //Fri Oct 06 01:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017
```

So, I have to parse `060420150134` so that I get `06 Apr 2015 01:34` and for that my format is `ddMMyyyyHHMM`

But I get here `Fri Oct 06 01:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017`

So i'm doing what's wrong? How to parse here?

Comment: You're using `MM` twice. The second one should be `mm`, for minutes rather than months. (I'd also suggest that the bulk of the code in the question is irrelevant; you just need three lines: create the SimpleDateFormat, parse the text, print the result.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse a date from string gives exception in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092277/parse-a-date-from-string-gives-exception-in-android)

Comment: @JonSkeet so MM is used for month and mm for minutes ? Am I right?

Comment: JonSkeet is correct....@JonSkeet, You should put it as answer.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes, he just missed some points here

Comment: @Opiatefuchs No, because this is effectively just a typo question, IMO. I voted to close rather than answering... I'd rather note encourage questions which are just about tiny slips of date formats which are easily fixed by reading the docs. (They're unlikely to help others - as witnessed by the fact that the OP didn't find the various duplicates of this question. It's not like this is the first time that MM and mm have been confused.)

Comment: that´s true....that´s really true... :)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, you are absolutely correct, its just a typo question regarding to you, but for me it's not a copy-paste error, or typing error, I never used these things before, so it's a proper answer to my question which saved my lot of hours, and so you deserve here some points for that

Comment: and now I got my answer, so yes you can now raise as many close flags as you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the second MM (months) to mm (minutes):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatDateAndTime = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmm");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Log.v(TAG, "startDateTime: " + startDateTime + "stopDateTime: " + stopDateTime); 
//Fri Oct 06 01:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017   Fri Jan 06 04:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017
```

You output **date object**, not string. When you use this: *"startDateTime: " + startDateTime + "stopDateTime: " + stopDateTime*, java will call method **toString()** in stopDateTime and startDateTime objects.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "060420150134" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMuuuuHHmm" )
).atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )
```

## Using java.time

As the [correct accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29512724/642706) says, your formatting pattern is incorrect.

Also, you are using the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. See below for Android info.

The formatting pattern codes are similar but not exactly identical. So study the class doc for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
String input = "060420150134" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMuuuuHHmm" );
```

Your input string lacks any indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

If you know for certain the time zone  or offset intended for this data, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` or apply a `ZoneOffset` to get a `OffsetDateTime`. Apparently in your context UTC itself is intended.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).