# how to get yesterday date

Tags: java, android

I want to get yesterday date or date which is of not today but of the past. I am using this code -

```
Calendar calendarMessage = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarMessage.setTime(date);
        return calendarMessage.get(Calendar.YEAR) == calendarToday.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                calendarMessage.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == calendarToday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Can you please help me in this?

Comment: google has about 8.970 answers to your question. Have you tried it?

Comment: Try this by using -1 for incremental http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738369/how-to-add-days-into-the-date-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Try on this way ..

```
public static String getYesterdayDate() {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
System.out.println("Yesterday's date = "+ cal.getTime());

private String getYesterdayDateString() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);    
        return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```