# how to work with next/prev clicks to get the next date in sequence

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add days to a date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507377/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-java)

I need to get the next date, on click of next link, and get the previous date on click of previous link. How do I increment or decrement dates? I am not getting how to work with date to increment/decrement it.

Comment: @assylias my question is to increement /decrement a date

Comment: @user1195292 well, incrementing is adding 1 and decrementing is adding -1, so the linked question essentially has the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date date = formatter.parse(your_String_date);
cal.setTime(date);
```

Now do the below as shown:

for increment

```
cal.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );
```

for decrement

```
cal.add( Calendar.DATE, -1 );
```

If you want to increment/decrement more days then just replace 1 by your number of days.

Hope it will help you.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is the Calendar class of java.

Comment: thanks this is what i wanted to do for blackberry thanks

Comment: ,i have the date in the form of string as below  String dateCurrent = getSelectedDate(); ,how can i increment this?

Comment: @user1195292 I have edites the answer please check it.

Comment: ,Let me try,i will update here if it works /not

Comment: i dont have .parse method in the blackberry dateFormat API to get the date from string

Comment: @user1195292 If you are using java then use import java.text.DateFormat

Comment: its java ,but using Blackberry date api

Comment: you can use java date inside java.util.Date also same effect will be there.Is not it ?

Comment: i cannot find cal.add () in calendar api

Comment: @user1195292 link given in my answer.

Comment: I am using java.util.Calendar; but i cannot add the method cal.add

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use JodaTime instead of the standard date api, since it's easier to use and a JodaTime-like api will be added to Java 8 anyways.

With the standard api have a look at the Apache Commons Lang library and especially its `DateUtils` class, which has a `addDays(date, numberOfDays)` method.