# Adding a number to the day or month or year in a date

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add days to a date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507377/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-java)

Consider the date to be **19/05/2013** and the number to be **14**. I would like to get the resulting date after adding the number to the month.

Expected result is: 19/07/2014.

Comment: is it in java, JS or C# ???

Comment: @PradeepSimha I'm trying to avoid using built in methods offered by the libraries.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic You probably should have mentioned that in your question. Also, what's wrong with using the built in methods?

Comment: Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Comment: *"I'm trying to avoid using built in methods"*  That is information that should be in the question, as should what you tried, in order to achieve that.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic, reason for avoiding built-in methods?

Comment: Here is an answer in Java - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Comment: @PradeepSimha I am trying to avoid using built in methods in this case only. I am trying to improve the logical ability and validations.

Comment: You should not be trying to avoid the built-in methods. That's why they are built-in. In order to avoid you from reinventing the wheels. You should do that only if you want to shoot yourself in the feet. Is it what you want? You are not improving anything by avoiding them. You are shooting yourself or the people using and having to maintain your code.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic, these built in abstraction methods are provided so that you don't re-invent wheel and put more effort on business logic. _improve the logical ability and validations_ I don't think this is the best way to improve that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In .NET you could do use the [`AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) method:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 5, 19);
DateTime newDate = date.AddMonths(14);
```

As far as parsing a date from a string using a specified format you could use the [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.TryParseExact.aspx) method:

```
string dateStr = "19/05/2013";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // successfully parsed the string into a DateTime instance =>
    // here we could add the desired number of months to it and construct
    // a new DateTime
    DateTime newDate = date.AddMonths(14);
}
else
{
    // parsing failed => the specified string was not in the correct format
    // you could inform the user about that here
}
```

Comment: Yeap, correct. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can [DateTime.AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) to add months.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 5, 19);
DateTime newDate = date.AddMonths(14);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); // today is the default
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // number of days to add (1)
c.getTime();  // The new date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **[AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)** to add the specified number of months to the value of this instance.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 5, 19);   // (yyyy,MM,dd)
DateTime dt = date.AddMonths(14);
```