# How to add month to a Datetime object?

Tags: c#, date

I want to add one month to the DateTime object but this object format is "dd/MM/yyyy"
When I add one month it increases one day, but this is not what I need.

Here is the code.

```
DateTime installmentdate = baseDate.AddMonths(1);
```

Suppose `baseDate` is 10/2/2014 when I add one month to date it becomes 10/3/2014
Please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working according to you. `.AddMonths()` is the way to do it; maybe you're parsing it wrong in the first place?

Comment: when we add one month it will add 1 days

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454854/adding-a-number-to-the-day-or-month-or-year-in-a-date

Comment: 10th March is a month after 10th Feb, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the dateformat and after that apply .AddMonths() method.

```
DateTime installmentDate=Convert.toDateTime(baseDate.tostring("MM/dd/yyyy")).AddMonths(1);
```

Comment: Why are you converting a `DateTime` -> `string` -> `DateTime`, it is not needed

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct , your date format is `dd/MM/yyyy` , adding one month to

```
 dd/MM/yyyy
 10/02/2014
```

become

```
 dd/MM/yyyy
 10/03/2014
```

You can change your format to `MM/dd/yyyy` for your need !

Answer (score 3):

DateTime doesn't have any format, you need to control the format where you display it using the `MM\dd\yyyy` format for its string representation.

`.AddMonths` does exactly what it says, so `DateTime installmentdate = baseDate.AddMonths(1);` is correct way and the `DateTime` incremented by 1 month is assigned to `installmentdate`

you only have to format the part where you display `installmentdate`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code, you are just having problem with the parsing of `baseDate`,

Your `baseDate` calculation should be something like,

```
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime baseDate = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateInString, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
```

And then you can continue with your above code, which is

```
DateTime installmentdate = baseDate.AddMonths(1);
```