# Android Calendar: Get to the future day

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, alarmmanager

i want to set an alarm to the specific date choosen by user, when i set to the day before current day, it sets it to past date, i want it to set to future.

Here is my Calendar set code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour.getHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.Monday);
```

let's say today is thursday, when i set date to monday, i want it to set to 4 days later, but it sets to 3 days before, to past monday

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add days to a date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507377/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following "technology":

1. calculate the days' difference between the current day and the day that you want to set to the calender in the future like this for example

   ```
   //future date
   Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
   thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour.getHour());
   thatDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
   thatDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   thatDay.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
   thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.Monday);

   //current date
   Calendar newDay = Calendar.getInstance();

   long diff = thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - newDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis

   //result in days
   long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
   ```
2. add to the calendar so many days as you calculated in step 1 like this for example:

   ```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour.getHour());
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
   calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, daysCount); // Add daysCount days to current date
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should `add` and not `set`. Once you add the `Calendar` instance will advance or substract (you can add negative, also) correctly.

By setting one of the properties you may have to handle all rounds and carries.