# Add number of days to date android

Tags: android, date

User will input a date and he/she will input days to add to it.

Like this:
**Date:** 1/1/2015
**Days to add:** 20

The **output** should be 1/21/2015

I am wondering how to do that. I am beginner in android. T__T *cries* I tried other sources but i don't understand them at all. THANKS

THE USER WILL SUPPLY THE DATE TO ADD AND THE NUMBER OF DAYS TO ADD. All other sources only explain adding the current date with the number of days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add days to a date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507377/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the string to a date first.

```
     SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
      try {
        Date myDate = dateParser.parse("01/01/2015");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(myDate);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 20);
        Date newDate = c.getTime();
        String newFormattedDate = dateParser.format(newDate);//01/21/2015
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //handle exception

    }
```

Comment: i will try this. wait

Comment: ARIGATOU GOZAIMASU , you have saved my life, stranger. *bow*